# event.target.value in Toast is undefined in LWC

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have trouble showing a clicked value on Toast.
I would appreciate it if you could help me!
The details are written below.
Thanks in advance!

[what I want to do]
Show the value of the selected link on Toast.
For example, when 'First' in the following picture is clicked, show 'First'.

[image]

[problem]
event.target.value is undefined even though I set the value in html.
[image]

[resources]
hello.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Hello!" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <template for:each={accounts} for:item="acc">
      <li key={acc.Id}>
        <a onclick={handleButtonClick} value={acc.Name}>{acc.Name}</a>
      </li>
    </template>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

hello.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
  accounts = [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'First',
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Second',
    },
  ];

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    const toast = new ShowToastEvent ({
      title: 'Hello!',
      message: 'Hello value: ' + event.target.value,
      variant: 'info'
    });
    console.log('event.target: ' + event.target.toString());
    this.dispatchEvent(toast);
  }
}
```

[What I confirmed]
event.target.toString() shows nothing in console.

Comment: see if event.detail works better (event.detail.value etc)

Comment: @eyescream Thanks for your comment. I tried but didn't work either :(

Comment: it might be because technically your code is bit weird... I mean "<a>" don't really have value, buttons do. Try `<a data-name={acc.Name}` and then `event.target.dataset.name` , `event.detail.dataset.name` or `event.currentTarget.dataset.name`? It's called "data attributes"

Comment: @eyescream I tried all of them, but this time Toast didn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but here's why it wasn't working.

You are using an *anchor* tag `a`, and this tag doesn't have the `value` attribute, when you add an attribute that doesn't belong to a tag it is called **custom attribute** and you can get it in a different way:

```js
event.target.getAttribute("value")
```

If you were using a button, this change wouldn't be necessary because the `button` tag does have a `value` attribute.

Also, if these options you have are going to have the behaviour of a button, then you should use a button. If you are using *anchor* tags just for the style, then you should just give the same style to the buttons.